# How do I STOP a webpage being auto scrolled again and again after it reaches to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am a newbie and trying to implement a JS code via Greasemonky that auto scrolls till the very bottom of the page. But if I scroll up, it keeps scrolling again so I want it to stop scrolling once I click a stop button.

```
// Scrolls till the bottom
setInterval(function(s){scrollBy(0,s||10000)},1000);


//script that creates a button
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
input.value = 'Stop scrolling';
input.onclick = stopScroll; 
document.body.appendChild(input);

//I need help here, not sure how to use clearInterval.
function stopScroll()
{
  clearInterval();      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, declare variable interval

```
var interval = setInterval(function(s){scrollBy(0,s||10000)},1000);
```

and then clean it in function

```
function stopScroll()
{
clearInterval(interval);      
}
```

Comment: [Here is the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval).